# Retry after catching an exception

Tags: python

Could you help me with this.

I created this code to provide a grade (A,B,C...) when a numeric input is given by the user.

```
try:
    grade = float(inp)
    if grade > 1:
        print ("Out of range")
    elif grade >= 0.9:
        print ("A")
    elif grade >= 0.8:
        print ("B")
    elif grade >= 0.7:
        print ("C")
    elif grade >=0.6:
        print ("D")
    elif grade <= 0.5:
        print("F")
    else:
        print("wrong value")

except:
            print ("Error- Please type a number between 1.0 and 0.0")
```

if the user types a non numeric answer how can i automatize the repetition of the code?

Comment: a grade in the range (0.5, 0.6) returns "wrong value". why is having a grade in this range wrong? And why having a negative grade is allowed and considered an F?

Comment: thank you for the observation. I corrected the line   elif grade <= 0.59:
        print("F") .

Comment: so now it will give the error in the range (0.59, 0.6). Why did you use the number 0.59 and not 0.6?

Comment: No, im sorry i couldn't block negatives. Could you help me with that as well?

Comment: `elif grade < 0: print ("Wrong value")` and remove your else

Comment: done. you're right